# Why is my css animation with scroll don't work on hosted platforms like netlify, render. But, Works well on local

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

I'm developing website by using react. I did two animations as box-revealing kinda stuff with data-aos scroll js library and scss. But, it doesn't work on hosted environment. this is live link  https://gulfmining-group.netlify.app/  the elements that i implemented animation are not even visible. For eg-: You won't see the header on about page or image next to it .Please Help!

`

```
@mixin box-reveal-animation {

  .box-reveal {
    display: inline-block;
    // transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin: right;
    -ms-transform-origin: right;
    transform-origin: right;



    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      top: 0;
      left: -20px;
      right: 0;
      width: 130%;
      height: 110%;
      background: rgb(68, 97, 173);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ADD039 63%, #ceeb71 78%, #d2e78b 100%);
      -webkit-transform-origin: left;
      -ms-transform-origin: left;
      transform-origin: left;
      transition: 0.8s ease-in;



    }

    &::before[data-aos="custom-box-animation"] {
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);


    }
  }

  .box-reveal.aos-init.aos-animate {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);

  }

  .box-reveal.aos-init.aos-animate::before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.05);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(0.05);
    transform: scaleX(0.05);



  }

}

@mixin black-box-reveal {
  .black-box-reveal {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
    transition: 0.9s;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    transform-origin: bottom;

    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      inset: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #141414;
      -webkit-transform-origin: top;
      transform-origin: top;
      -webkit-transition: 0.9s ease-in;
      transition: 0.9s ease-in;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
      transition-delay: 1s;
    }

    &::before[data-aos="custom-black-box-reveal"] {
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
      transform: scaleY(1);
    }
  }

  .black-box-reveal.aos-init.aos-animate {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }

  .black-box-reveal.aos-init.aos-animate::before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}



 <div className='AboutIntro'>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="left-col">
                        <h2 className='box-reveal' data-aos="custom-box-animation" data-aos-offset="200">About US</h2>
                        <p data-aos="fade"data-aos-duration="900">Founded in 2005, Gulf Mining Group (GMG) is a leading player in Oman's mineral industries. With a rich history of mining and mineral development, GMG's diverse interests span Chrome, Manganese, Marble, Limestone, and more.

                            Driven by a commitment to harness Oman's mineral potential, GMG has grown rapidly to become one of Oman's largest mining companies. Discover our story and explore our journey on the full "About Us" page.</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="right-col">
                        <div className="image-container black-box-reveal"data-aos="custom-black-box-reveal"data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-offset="300">
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580420232349-3eefa50d2423?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1432&q=80" alt="" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you compile and convert scss into css before deployment? If not you have to make sure that your server supports scss and compile it on the fly

Comment: yeah, i compile it using Live sass compiler...  and import the css into react components. eg:    import '../../styles/AboutIntro.css'  like this

Answer (score 0):

By the way , i solved it by myself! i just had to add  !important to it.

```
 &::before[data-aos="custom-box-animation"] {
       transform: scaleX(1)!important;
 
 
    }
```

but i don't get how it worked on local system tho , but not on production.If anyone knows the reason. I'd really appreciate if you could tell me about it.